# create 2 rounded corner rectangular with fireworks

Tags: fireworks

How to create 2 rounded corner at one side of the rectangular in Adobe Fireworks? while sharp corner at another side of the rectangular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just draw a rectangle with the rounded rectangle tool. Then use the pointer tool and select the rectangle you just created. You will see four diamonds. If you drag one of the diamonds you will see that you can alter the four corners simultaneously. If you press the alt (option) key while dragging you can alter one individual corner of the rectangle.

Another possibility would be to create two rectangles. One with rounded corners and one without. Then use the punch paths command.